# Modifying Calendar control asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

We are using asp:Calendar control (month view) in our touch screen application (asp web forms). When user touches the day on the month, it fires the on click event. The issue that was brought up, that user has to press exactly on the number, or the click event won't fire up. My boss wants us to change it, that if user presses anywhere in the date cell, it should fire the event. I looked into adding the button or link or hidden field into the cell on rendering (script), but there is no way to attach click event... Is there any way to accomplish it? If not - is there any other control that would show the whole month and be customizable?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried jQueryUI datepicker? That's quite popular and easy to set up.

Comment: I need to show the whole current month on the page, with all dates listed, and ability to go to the next month. jquery DatePicker only allows 1 date...

Comment: Not true. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: I meant I need the whole month to show at all times on the screen, static, not a drop down list with whole month...

Comment: have you actually looked at that demo link? The whole calendar is visible all the time, it doesn't appear/disappear.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look at the last link, just googled jQueryUI datepicker before and didn't see it... My apologies...